# how to control Android ScrollView to go all the way to top or bottom but never middle?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a fragment with a scrollview that holds a long layout essentially representing 2 different sections that are related, what I want is to control the scrollview so when the user wants to scroll down it always goes all the way down and can never be in the middle so it will never reveal partially the top or bottom parts, same effect backwards when you want to scroll up it just takes over and goes all the way up to reveal the top section of the layout fully.

It is basically how a vertical viewpager will behave but contained within a single long view.

I know how to programatically scroll up or down but I don't know how to avoid the user scrolling to just the middle, I'd like to hook up to some scroll event, detect the direction and go fully in either direction.

Comment: What have you tried? I think you can get the `ScrollView` height, then get the current scrolling position and then check the distance to each edge. At this point you can decide to which edge you want to animate your `ScrollView`. I think this logic should be in onTouch event, when they finish a gesture via `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

Comment: Why isn't using a vertical view pager with two views an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: I guess the transition effect of the scroll with the little bounce was preferable and easier to achieve within a single view, but really if I can't get it to work within a single view I'll try a pager.